# The Gnome software store is looking strange

Tags: gnome, 22.04, software-center

I have never really used it, but now I opened it, and it has these strange white tiles around the logos of the applications and I can't even read the name of the apps. I assume it has something to do with the themes I set with Gnome Tweaks. Has anyone experienced this issue?

[image]